# Why isn't this a[1+2] accepted? - ANTLR4 Grammar error

Tags: antlr4, context-free-grammar

```
/* Casual has to be the filename */
grammar Grammar;

/* non-terminals start with lowercase */

prog: (comment|declaration|NEWLINE|SPACE|definition|statement)*EOF;

comment:
    '(*' (ANYCHAR|VARIABLE|SPACE|NEWLINE|number|operator)* '*)'
;

declaration:
    vname_type '('args_def?')' SPACE* ';'
;

vname_type:
    (VARIABLE) SPACE* ':' SPACE* type SPACE* refinement? /* Nomes das funções não podem começar com números */
;

type:
    (DOUBLE|INT|BOOLEAN|FLOAT|STRING)
;

refinement:
    'where' SPACE* (VARIABLE) SPACE* operator SPACE* (number|string_lit|TRUE|FALSE)
;

number:
    (NUMBER_INT|NUMBER_FLOAT)
;

string_lit:
    '"' (ANYCHAR|number|operator|SPACE)* '"'
;

statement:
    (return_statement|expression|value|if_statement|while_statement|arrays)
;

value:
    vname_type '=' SPACE* (number|string_lit|VARIABLE) SPACE* ';'
;

arrays:
    (VARIABLE '['position']' ';'
    |'get_array()['position']' ';'
    )
;

position:
    pos
    |pos SPACE* (MATH_OPERATOR) SPACE* pos
    |pos SPACE* (MATH_OPERATOR) SPACE* pos SPACE* (MATH_OPERATOR) SPACE* position
;
pos:
    (NUMBER_INT|VARIABLE)
;

expression:
    (function_call
    | (number|VARIABLE|ANYCHAR|SPACE)*';')
;

function_call:
    VARIABLE'('args_value? ')' ';'
;

return_statement:
    'return' SPACE* (VARIABLE|number) SPACE* ';'
;

definition:
    (function)
;

function:
    vname_type SPACE* '('SPACE* args_def? SPACE*')' SPACE*
    '{'
    (statement|SPACE)*
    '}'
;

if_statement:
    'if' SPACE* boolean_expression SPACE* '{'
    statement*
    '}' else_statement?
;

else_statement:
    'else' '{' statement* '}'
;

while_statement:
    'while' boolean_expression '{' statement* '}'
;

boolean_expression:
    (conditions_values
    | conditions_values operator conditions_values
    | (conditions_values operator conditions_values operator boolean_expression)
    )
;

conditions_values:
    VARIABLE
    |TRUE
    |FALSE
    |number
;

args_def:
    vname_type SPACE* (',' vname_type SPACE*)*
;

args_value:
    (number|string_lit|TRUE|FALSE) (',' (number|string_lit|TRUE|FALSE))*
;

operator:
    (MATH_OPERATOR | BOOLEAN_OPERATOR)
;

/* terminals start with uppercase, and can be defined using regular expressions. */

DOUBLE: 'Double';
INT: 'Int';
BOOLEAN: 'Boolean';
FLOAT: 'Float';
STRING: 'String';
TRUE: 'true';
FALSE: 'false';
NUMBER_INT: [0-9_]+; /* Underscore can be in any position */
NUMBER_FLOAT: ('.'[0-9]+|[0-9]+.[0-9]+);
MATH_OPERATOR: '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '%';
BOOLEAN_OPERATOR: '&&' | '||' | '==' | '!=' | '>=' | '<=' | '<' | '>' ;
NEWLINE : [\r\n]+ -> skip;
SPACE: (' '|'\t') -> skip;
VARIABLE: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
ANYCHAR: (.)+?;
```

So this is my grammar, and I can't figure out why I get this error: mismatched input '1+2' expecting {NUMBER_INT, VARIABLE}
When trying to parse a[1+2]

Im trying to make a new language and Im trying to access a position of an array
I don't know what else to try to change on the grammar
I've tried changing order if it was the case
But if I write a[1+ 2] it works so I don't how the space makes such a big difference

Comment: Why does this question have the "java" tag?

Comment: well antlr4 is in java and thats what I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your grammar does not accept `a[1+2]` but does accept `a[1+ 2]` is because of the rule:

```
NUMBER_FLOAT: ('.'[0-9]+|[0-9]+.[0-9]+);
//                             ^
//                             ^
//                             ^
//                             This matches any char!
```

causing `1+2` to become a `NUMBER_FLOAT` instead of 3 separate tokens. You need to wrap the `.` in quotes

```
NUMBER_FLOAT
 : '.' [0-9]+
 | [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+
 ;
```

which could be written as:

```
NUMBER_FLOAT
 : [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+
 ;
```

I highly suggest you make a more general `expression` rule and use that rule in your `arrays` rule (and other rules):

```
arrays
 : VARIABLE '[' expression ']' ';'
 | 'get_array' '(' ')' '[' expression ']' ';'
 ;

expression
 : '(' expression ')'
 | expression MATH_OPERATOR expression
 | expression BOOLEAN_OPERATOR expression
 | function_call
 | NUMBER_INT
 | NUMBER_FLOAT
 | VARIABLE
 | ANYCHAR
 | TRUE
 | FALSE
 ;
```

Also, remove the `SPACE`s from your parser rules since you are already `skip`ping them in the lexer.

A quick demo:

```
grammar Grammar;

prog
 : (COMMENT | declaration | definition | statement)* EOF
 ;

declaration
 : vname_type '(' args_def? ')' ';'
 ;

vname_type
 : VARIABLE ':' type refinement?
 ;

type
 : DOUBLE
 | INT
 | BOOLEAN
 | FLOAT
 | STRING
 ;

refinement
 : 'where' expression
 ;

statement
 : return_statement
 | expression
 | value
 | if_statement
 | while_statement
 | arrays
 ;

value
 : vname_type '=' expression ';'
 ;

arrays
 : VARIABLE '[' expression ']' ';'
 | 'get_array' '(' ')' '[' expression ']' ';'
 ;

expression
 : '(' expression ')'
 | expression MATH_OPERATOR expression
 | expression BOOLEAN_OPERATOR expression
 | function_call
 | NUMBER_INT
 | NUMBER_FLOAT
 | VARIABLE
 | ANYCHAR
 | TRUE
 | FALSE
 ;

function_call
 : VARIABLE '(' args_value? ')' ';'
 ;

return_statement
 : 'return' expression ';'
 ;

definition
 : function
 ;

function
 : vname_type '('args_def? ')' '{' statement* '}'
 ;

if_statement
 : 'if' expression '{' statement* '}' else_statement?
 ;

else_statement
 : 'else' '{' statement* '}'
 ;

while_statement
 : 'while' expression '{' statement* '}'
 ;

args_def
 : vname_type (',' vname_type)*
 ;

args_value
 : expression (',' expression)*
 ;

COMMENT: '(*' .*? '*)';
DOUBLE: 'Double';
INT: 'Int';
BOOLEAN: 'Boolean';
FLOAT: 'Float';
STRING: 'String';
TRUE: 'true';
FALSE: 'false';
NUMBER_INT: [0-9_]* [0-9] [0-9_]*;
NUMBER_FLOAT: [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+;
MATH_OPERATOR: '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '%';
BOOLEAN_OPERATOR: '&&' | '||' | '==' | '!=' | '>=' | '<=' | '<' | '>' ;
SPACES: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
VARIABLE: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
STRING_LIT: '"' .*? '"';
ANYCHAR: . ;
```

If you now parse `a[1+2];`, you'll get:

[image]

Comment: You see my grammar accepts a[1+ 2] I just don't get why it doesn't accept a[1+2]

How does that space changes everything

Edit: English

Comment: Because `1+2` is tokenized as a single `NUMBER_FLOAT`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I didn't realize I made that mistake
I meant to write '.' because I want the actual dot and not every char